# Spring JUnit .properties file does not work

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, junit

Here is the annotation configuration in my test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml","classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
```

The `applictionCotnext.xml` include `jpa-context.xml`, database configuration was in `jpa-context.xml`, and dataSource configured by `jdbc.properties`.

When I run the test method,  Could not open connection occurred caused by all value in jdbc.properties were null.

Then I add a method for access properties in the same test class.

```
@Inject
private ApplicationContext context;
@Test
public void accessProperties(){
    MutablePropertySources sources = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context)
                .getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
    System.out.println("jdbcUrl=="+sources.iterator().next().getProperty("jdbcUrl"));
}
```

I got the `jdbc` Url success. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache Maven you need to place your properties file in src/test/resources. That should pick up your properties.